# What's up with this JavaScript pattern?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I saw this pattern:

```
Money = (function() {
    function Money(rawString) {
        this.cents = this.parseCents(rawString);
    }
});
```

in this [CoffeeScript screencast preview](http://peepcode.com/system/uploads/2011/peepcode-coffeescript-preview.mov). (The homepage for the screencast is [here](http://peepcode.com/products/coffeescript).)

Now, I don't understand this pattern. There is a `Money` function that contains a `Money` function. What's that about?

Could someone explain?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As quoted, there's no point to that pattern other than that the outer `Money` symbol can be deleted from the `window` object (except on IE7 and below, but that's another story) because it's a normal (implicit) property of `window` (as opposed to a `var` or a symbol deriving from a function declaration). But even then, the outer `Money` symbol receives a function that does absolutely nothing. Could it be misquoted?

For instance, here's a fairly standard patttern:

```
Money = (function() {
    var someCompletelyPrivateVariable;

    function doSomethingCompletelyPrivate() {
    }

    function Money(rawString) {
        this.cents = this.parseCents(rawString);
    }

    return Money;
})();
```

That's the module pattern, and it lets you have completely private variables and functions (both illustrated) whilst only having one public symbol. But I've had to edit a fair bit to create that (the most significant edits being the `return Money;` at the end and the addition of `()` after the anonymous function so we're *calling* it rather than just defining it.

Comment: @Crowder Could you elaborate? Why can it be deleted?

Comment: There's not much point to a constructor that returns something other than `this`.

Comment: @RobG: The thing I've added a return to isn't a constructor, it's a scoping function. Its purpose is purely to make private scope. It returns a function which *might* be a constructor function. Without more scope, we couldn't know.

Answer (score 15):

Using the CoffeeScript code that the video claims is a proper conversion...

```
class Money
    constructor: (rawString) ->
        @cents = @parseCents rawString
```

...CoffeeScript will generate the following, which is basically identical to @T.J. Crowder's answer:

```
var Money;
Money = (function() {
  function Money(rawString) {
    this.cents = this.parseCents(rawString);
  }
  return Money;
})();
```

I'm just posting this to show what CoffeeScript *actually* does, and that the video does not represent the reality.

You can see the conversion if you [visit the site](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) and click the "Try CoffeeScript" button.

Please do *not* "accept" this answer.

---

**EDIT:**

To add some private variable usage that utilizes the scope, you could do this:

```
class Money
    priv=0
    constructor: (rawString) ->
        @cents = @parseCents rawString
        @id = priv++
```

...which renders as:

```
var Money;
Money = (function() {
  var priv;
  priv = 0;
  function Money(rawString) {
    this.cents = this.parseCents(rawString);
    this.id = priv++;
  }
  return Money;
})();
```

By the way, I know nothing about CoffeeScript. Its syntax looks confusing to me, but perhaps just because I'm not accustomed to it.

I like JavaScript the way it is (especially with the new and yet to come changes).

Comment: Nice one. So it's setting up a private scope as I mentioned, but not utilizing it. (And it's preventing deletion by using `var`, but hey, it was an edgy use case anyway...)

Comment: It's a lapsus then. The producer forgot to include the `return Money;` statement and the trailing `()`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yes I assume it was just meant to be a short example. Actually using the scope would make more sense.

Comment: @Šime: Yeah, those are pretty big omissions.

Comment: @Šime: Yup. And despite what @RightSaidFred said, I think this is the right answer and the one to accept -- because it does what you asked, explains what's going on. I could explain the JavaScript (and what was probably wrong with it), but he explained the broader thing (and showed that it's probably an error in the video, which the rest of us only speculated on). @RightSaidFred: It's actually perfectly reasonable JavaScript syntax. It's moderately advanced, but a pattern I probably use every other day. :-)

Comment: @RightSaidFred Me too `:)` (I too like JavaScript the way it is.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I meant that the CoffeeScript syntax looks confusing. The JavaScript is easier to read in my opinion. :)

Comment: @RightSaidFred I agree with @Crowder. Please revoke the do-not-accept request `:)`

Comment: @Šime: Ganging up on me huh? ;)

Comment: @RightSaidFred: *"I meant that the CoffeeScript syntax looks confusing."* Sorry, I totally misunderstood. With you now (and completely agree).

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of the screencast mentioned, and the source of the snippet. A few clarifications:

- The context in which the snippet was mentioned was in an animated comparison of JavaScript and CoffeeScript syntax.
- It was intentionally simplified so as to not add extra confusion in the context of the CoffeeScript concept being taught at that exact moment in the video (the video was not trying to teach JavaScript constructor or class syntax).
- You can get the full JavaScript text of any CoffeeScript snippet by running it through the CoffeeScript compiler as shown in the screencast, or by running it on the official CoffeeScript website.

I'll add a clarification to the video and preview mentioned above.

Otherwise, the other explanations here on Stack Overflow are correct. If you're building a JavaScript class you should return the current object and call the anonymous function shown above. But that's not the point of CoffeeScript. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like a real example, the grouping operator of the "outer" function is pointless and as TJ says, it does absolutely nothing. Called as a constructor, it will return an empty object.

@TJ - the quote is correct, you need to watch about 40 seconds of the video.

Comment: I think it must be misquoted in the video.

Comment: @Crowder I guess I'll better contact the producer of that screen-cast then `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Money = (function() {
    var uid = 0;
    function Money(rawString) {
        this.cents = this.parseCents(rawString);
        this.uid = uid++;
    }
    return Money;
})();
```

Another use case of this pattern is to have local variables that act as if there statically bound to the function.

This is subtly different from the module pattern because your adding static private information to a function.  Instead of packaging data and returning an object which has some local variables in scope.

The other option for achieving this would be using `Money.uid` but that would be public.

Answer (score 1):

There are three things going on here:

First, as other answerers have noted, the code given in the PeepCode screencast and cited in the question has a couple of mistakes. There is a `return`, and the outer function is called.

Second, as T.J. noted, this is a module pattern. You can execute arbitrary code in CoffeeScript `class` blocks, and variables obey the same scoping rules as in other functions. So, for instance, you could write

```
class HashedPassword
  salt = Math.random()
  constructor: (password) ->
    @value = hash password, salt
```

in which case `salt` is visible only within the `HashedPassword` class definition.

Finally, it should be noted that this is the only place that CoffeeScript ever uses "named" functions (those declared with `function foo()` rather than `foo = function()`). Named functions are great for stack traces and such, but they cause inconsistencies between IE (< 9) and other browsers *unless* scoped in a module like this (see the [CoffeeScript FAQ](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ), heading "Is there any way to name functions, for reflection and recursion?"). So a secondary use of the `class` syntax is to safely declare named functions.

I hope that answers your question, Šime.

Answer (score 0):

The outer Money function takes no arguments. The inner Money function captures rawString via closure. The advantage here is that you're not polluting the global namespace with the inner Money function definition.

EDIT: I would agree with TJ that the pattern as it stands is useless. It doesn't do anything and the outer function is used solely for scoping. Without seeing the screencast author's complete example, it's hard to tell where he is going with this.

Comment: Yes, but we're polluting the (outermost) namespace with the outer `Money` function definition. So how is not polluting the namespace with the inner one an advantage?

Comment: You are encapsulating the function Money(rawString) thus preventing others from calling it.

Comment: But you seemingly are polluting the global namespace with the outer parameter-less Money() definition. I still don't understand how you're gaining an advantage. Can you clarify? Also, where is the rawString variable stored? Does that have to be defined elsewhere in the global namespace?

Comment: Also that doesn't explain what it's doing at all.  It's a function that returns nothing, with no way to call the inner `Money` function.

Comment: @Renesis I guess that renders it useless (= that pattern is not functional).